# How does one rigorously prove $\mathcal{P}(\{a,b\})=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Clearly, every element of $\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ is a subset of $\{a,b\}$, but I do not see how to rigorously prove the reverse implication. Using the formula for the cardinality of a finite set it can be deduced that $\mathcal{P}(\{a,b\})$ has $4$ elements, but surely there must be a more elementary way to prove such an elementary fact?

Comment: Clarify for me - what exactly is the "reverse implication," here?

Comment: I don't think there is much to be shown. A subset of $\{a,b\}$ clearly has to be one of the sets given.

Comment: Just go back to the definition, together with the fact that two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements. If $X \in \mathcal{P}(\{a, b\})$, then $X$ is a subset of $\{a, b\}$. So the elements of $X$ can only consist of $a$ and $b$ and so they must be on the list you wrote.

Comment: @Eevee Trainer How can we be sure that every subset of \{a,b\} is an element of $\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: @NAnotapplicable ask yourself is $S \subseteq \{a,b\}$, then $|S| \leq 2$. If $|S|=0$, then $S=\emptyset$, if $|S|=1$, then either $S=\{a\}$ or $S=\{b\}$.

Comment: #Eclipse Sun Yes it's very obvious but I'm looking for a rigorous proof. Sorry if this question is not appropriate for this site but I couldn't find anywhere else where this had been asked.

Comment: Consider a subset $A$ of $\{a,b\}.$ Then occurs one of four following cases: 1. $a\in A$ and $b\in A,$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $S \in \mathcal{P}(\{a,b\})$.  Then by the law of excluded middle, we have $a \in S \vee a \notin S$; and similarly, we have $b \in S \vee b \notin S$.  This splits into four cases: $(a\in S \wedge b\in S) \vee (a\in S \wedge b \notin S) \vee (a\notin S \wedge b\in S) \vee (a\notin S \wedge b\notin S)$.  I'll illustrate one particular case, where $a \in S$ and $b \notin S$.

Now, for any $x$, suppose $x \in S$.  Since $S \in \mathcal{P}(\{a,b\})$, $S \subseteq \{a,b\}$, so this implies $x \in \{a,b\}$, which is equivalent to $x = a \vee x = b$.  But in the second case, $x = b$, $x \in S$, and $b \notin S$ leads to a contradiction.  Therefore, $x \in S \rightarrow x = a$; and conversely, $x = a \rightarrow x \in S$ by substitution with our assumption $a \in S$.  In conclusion, we have shown $\forall x, x \in S \leftrightarrow x = a \leftrightarrow x \in \{ a \}$.  By the extensionality axiom, this implies that $S = \{ a \}$, so $S \in \{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Combining the cases, we will eventually get a proof of $\forall S, S \in \mathcal{P}(\{a,b\}) \rightarrow S \in \{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.  For the other direction, $S \in \{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ implies $S = \emptyset \vee S = \{a\} \vee S=\{b\} \vee S=\{a,b\}$.  I will leave to you to do a proof by cases that each of these implies $S \in \mathcal{P}(\{a,b\})$.

Therefore, we have $\forall S, S \in \mathcal{P}(\{a,b\}) \leftrightarrow S \in \{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$, which by another application of the extensionality axiom implies that $\mathcal{P}(\{a,b\}) = \{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: Bravo! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @NAnotapplicable Out of genuine curiosity, how is this any different than enumeration of the sets in your eyes? During the construction of the cases of consideration, you are forced to explicitly write out every possible subset. The remainder of the proof ends up being even more complicated than the combinatorial argument.

Comment: @RandomMathGuy You are right: the answer I selected is indeed more complicated than yours. I prefer it, however, because it relies directly on the definitions of power set, pair set, etc. rather than introducing the more complicated (as I see it) concept of cardinality, which, although undoubtedly useful, did not seem necessary to prove such a simple assertion. My sense of 'mathematical simplicity' is clearly not the same as yours; both answers have their merits and weaknesses. They're both correct though, (and both appreciated), so which one I prefer is a subjective matter. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are not going to find a more "elementary" way of working with finite powersets precisely because the powerset operation is axiomatic. The fact that such a set exists is given, you don't have to prove it; thus verifying that a given set is a powerset **must** boil down to enumerating the elements.

Now, I'm no logician, so I could be wrong. If someone out there has better insight then down-vote this into oblivion.

Comment: But even after enumerating the elements, how can you know that there is not a subset that you missed?

Comment: @NAnotapplicable If you believe the counting argument for the size of the powerset being $2^{|S|}$, then all you have to do is show that all elements are distinct and that there are the right number of them. If you don't believe the counting argument we will need to go back and address something else that is foundational.

Comment: Thank you, I do indeed believe the counting argument and your proof is perfectly valid. Nonetheless, it seems to me that there must be a simpler way to prove this.

Comment: @NAnotapplicable The issue I'm dancing around is that this **is** the simple way to prove that a set is a powerset. It is **ugly** because it is purely computational, but that doesn't make it complicated. I really meant what I wrote; you are dealing with an object that is at the ground floor of ZFC. There is a very good chance that proving a finite set is the powerset of some other set can **only** be done via enumeration.

Comment: Okay then. I admit I'm not fully satisfied but if that really is the simplest way than I guess I never will be... Thanks for your input.